# How to set up profile image from firebase database

Tags: ios, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiimageview

Hey I am new to Xcode and need of assistance in uploading my profile image from firebase database to my user profile. I have receive no errors so far but the image is not appearing when my user logs in, the image is already stored in firebase but when I attach the UIImageView to the user profile the image shows up blank do anyone have a solution to fix this code to make my image appear on the user profile once they log in it should be automatic?

```
               typealias blockCompletedWith = (Bool, String) -> Void


               //path: folder name if any followed by name of image
  func uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: Data, path: String, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
                     let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                      metadata.contentType = "profileImage.jpg"

                    let store = Storage.storage()
                    let storeRef = store.reference().child(path)
                    let _ = storeRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
                       guard let _ = metadata else {
                       print("error occured: \(error.debugDescription)")
                            blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                                    return
                                                  }

                storeRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                     if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {
                     blockCompletedWith(true, urlText)
                                                      }
                                             else {
                                blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                                                      }
                                                  })
                                              }
                                          }


               if let profileImageUrl = dictionary?["gs://tunnel-vision-d6825.appspot.com"] as? String {
                  let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
                       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                               if let error = error{
                               print("Error : \(error)")
                    return
                                }
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                            }
                    }.resume()

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use firebase storage to save images and put the image link into your database.

```
typealias blockCompletedWith = (Bool, String) -> Void

func uploadProfileImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        let path = "folderName/imagename.jpeg"
        self.uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: imageData!, path: path, blockCompletedWith: { (isSuccess, urlStr) in
            Utility.stopActivityIndicator()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if isSuccess {
                    print(urlStr)
                }
                else {
                    print("Error in uploading Image")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

-----------uploadImageToFirebaseStorage Method------------

```
//path: folder name if any followed by name of image
func uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: Data, path: String, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        let store = Storage.storage()
        let storeRef = store.reference().child(path)
        let _ = storeRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            guard let _ = metadata else {
                print("error occured: \(error.debugDescription)")
                blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                return
            }

            storeRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {
                    blockCompletedWith(true, urlText)
                }
                else {
                    blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is  (self.uploadImageToFirebaseStorage) @MohitKumar

Comment: This line calling the 2nd method written in the answer. I have updated the answer with clear separation. is it clear now?

Comment: yeah I understand but how do I fix this error (Value of type 'ProfileViewController' has no member 'uploadImageToFirebaseStorage') @MohitKumar

Comment: Just copy the second method and paste in you view controller.

Comment: the image still not appearing @MohitKumar

Comment: Have you enabled firebase storage?? If yes check for uploaded image in firebase storage on firebase console.

Comment: The photo is Already in firebase storage the user signed up with a photo I just need it to transfer from

Comment: Did you get an url after image uploading completion?? If yes please share that url.

Comment: url from firebase ? @MohitKumar

Comment: if so here it is https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tunnel-vision-d6825.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2FUgsS89nmNqV8EloEsNZYtrOyjsC3?alt=media&token=91e07b7b-4633-4f3f-a8bd-e7ebc5862191

Comment: That’s correct and you can save this url with the user profile and use some 3rd party library to load image from url in your image view. 3rd party libraries like sdwebimage, kingfisher etc

Comment: Because if you try to open this url in browser you can see the image as well

Comment: Why can’t I just use firebase @MohitKumar

Comment: You are using firebase...now you have 1 url and you need to load image from url to your image view, for that you can write your own code if you don’t want to use any library.

Comment: Can you help me write that code I’m new to this @MohitKumar

Comment: Install cocoa pods in your project. follow this url: https://cocoapods.org ..... After that you need to install https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage into your project and read https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage to place image to your imageview

Comment: firebase was never a issue the issue was my profile image never showed up that was already upload in firebase @MohitKumar

Comment: Try pods and sdwebimage

Comment: this didn't solve my problem at all I can't check off on this I'm still open to solutions @MohitKumar

Comment: After getting URL for image you need to store that image url in your firebase database. After that in a separate function get from firebase db and fetch image from url and set it on imageview.