# How would I upload this converted UIImage to Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, firebase-storage

I needed to convert my UI Image that I took with AV Camera Foundation into black and white, so after the user 'approves' the photo, I called this function:

```
func convertToGrayScale(with originalImage:UIImage, imageStyle:String) -> UIImage {
        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: imageStyle)
        currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: originalImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!,from: output!.extent)
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        return processedImage
    }
```

in this block of code:

```
// Save Image to Camera Roll
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let newImage = convertToGrayScale(with: image!, imageStyle: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
        let imageToSave = newImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil)
        uploadPhoto()
        // downloadPhoto()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

which is triggered when the user approves the photo.

Now, the problem is that while the image is black and white when it is saved to the camera roll, it is obviously not when it is uploaded to the storage, because the upload function (as seen below) passes the unconverted image into the storage:

```
// Upload to Firebase Storage
    func uploadPhoto() {
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(MyKeys.imagesFolder).child("\(imageName)")
        
        if let imageData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
                }
                print(metadata as Any)
                
        })
        }
        
        else {
            self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        }
```

I tried taking out the function and directly pasting the code into the @IBA Action function, but when I tried running it on my phone, I couldn't even save the image to the camera roll or even the storage. **How should I modify the functions to save this black and white image to the storage?**

Comment: If `saveButton` you declare `newImage` locally (`let newImage`) but then in `uploadPhoto` you are referring to `newImage` and it's not clear where that is. Is that a property somewhere? Do you mean to be setting that in `saveButton`?

Comment: @jnpdx Yes, sorry, I made a few edits to make it clearer. That was a mistake, NOT a property, and it was just `image` (the original UIImage before it was converted). That's why I'm asking–is there a way that I can upload my `newImage` with the `uploadPhoto()` function?

Comment: Why not just pass it as a parameter to `uploadPhoto`?

Comment: I tried doing that but it says it won't accept arguments

Comment: Oh nevermind that's obviously because I didn't create a function with parameters. I got it now, thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59872820/2781088